# Sum of a geometric series over natural density zero indices

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, power-series, summability-theory

It is well known that the geometric power series $%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}}
%EndExpansion
x^{k}$ is convergent to $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ for any $\left \vert x\right \vert <1
$. Is there any infinite set of density zero over which the sum of the corresponding series can be still evaluated? For example, can we find the sum of the series $%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{k\text{ is prime}}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle \sum \limits_{k\text{ is prime}}}
%EndExpansion
x^{k}$ for $0<x<1$?

Comment: Since the series for all natural indices converges, and the terms in the series are positive, the series for any subset of indices converges and the sum will be no greater than the sum for the whole series. Is your question whether there is a simply described zero natural density set of indices, $I$, so that $\sum\limits_{k\in I}x^k$ has a simple formula in terms of $x$?

Comment: Yes, the convergence of any such series is clear. Is there any nonempty set of density zero over which the sum of the corresponding series can be evaluated?

Comment: Then it would be good to ask that in the question. The answer you accepted does not answer that question so it is hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe my question is now more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fully depends on the zero density set you are looking at. Certainly all series converge but  it depends on what is the representation of that set. For instance, if the set is $\{\}$ the answer is 0, if the set is the powers of 2 then the sum is
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2^k}$$
and you could very fastly describe a set of zero density such that the sum cannot be written in closed form, such as Mersenne's primes, numbers of the form $\lfloor \pi n+e^n\rfloor$ and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you. Well. Is there any nonempty set of density zero over which the sum of the corresponding series can be evaluated?

Comment: You should add infinite :-)

Comment: Of course it should be infinite. Thanks.

Comment: And the fact that the density is over Z

Comment: I am sure there is such a set though. I'll give it a thought

Comment: Ok. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^2}$
is a Theta function.

Comment: Does it have another definition other than that sum?